# How to pass Custom template variables to footer template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want pass custom template variables to footer template.

In which file i need make changes to pass my customer template variables to footer template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event for email templates.

First of all, create an event with the name `email_order_set_template_vars_before`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
    <observer name="custom_email_variable"
              instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\CustomVar" />
</event>
```

Then, we make the observer class in which we put the code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class CustomVar implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Execute method
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $transportObject = $observer->getEvent()->getData('transportObject');

        $transportObject['custom_variable'] = $this->customMethod();
    }

    /**
     * Custom method
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function customMethod(): string
    {
        return 'Test custom var';
    }
}
```

Now, you will be able to call the `custom_variable` variable and you will receive the message from the return.

Comment: HI @Bogdan Pisica, is it work for all emails or only for order emails. I assume "email_order_set_template_vars_before" event works for order emails only.